# IDEA требует Master Password при подключении MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

Работаю в IntelijIDEA, хочу присоединить к проекту MySQL после всех настроек высвечивается окно и требует ввести Master Password. Где его взять? Я так понял это не пароль от БД.

Answer (score 2):

IDEA использует менеджер паролей для хранения используемых юзером паролей к различным системам. Обычно это [Keepass](http://keepass.info) - мастер пароль - это пароль доступа к менеджеру паролей.

Если не помните мастер пароль - можно тупо удалить его и создать заново.

[Подробнее здесь](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/passwords.html)

Comment: уже разобрался. Нажал кнопку reset. Пересоздал пароль и подключился к БД. Работаю дальше)